# Bootstrap 5 dropdown is not working on Angular 12

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-5, angular12

I'm trying to add the Bootstrap 5 dropdown in Angular 12 it's not working.

I have installed all the necessary packages, added them to the `angular.json` file.

Copied the exact example from Bootstrap 5 docs still not working.

In `angular.json` I have given

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Below is my HTML code (same as in Bootstrap 5 docs)

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data- 
bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I used the command `npm i` to install the packages without mentioning any version name so I guess the latest version was installed. Installed jQuery as the last resort read somewhere Bootstrap 5 doesn`t require jQuery. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

According to [Bootstrap 5 (Separate section)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#separate), Bootstrap 5 **requires @popperjs/core** but **not popperjs**. Hence you were installing and importing the wrong library.

FYI, Bootstrap 5 **[removed dependency on jQuery](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2020/06/16/bootstrap-5-alpha/)**.

---

### Solution 1: Install @popperjs/core

**Pre-requisite**: You have installed Bootstrap 5 with

```
npm install bootstrap@5
```

1. You are required to install `@popperjs/core` as dependencies. Via npm

```
npm install @popperjs/core
```

2. Import `@popperjs/core` into *angular.json*. **Popper (library) must come first (if you’re using tooltips or popovers), and then our JavaScript plugins.**

> angular.json

```
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

---

### Solution 2: Import Bootstrap as bundle

**Pre-requisite**: You have installed Bootstrap 5 with

```
npm install bootstrap@5
```

[Bootstrap bundle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#bundle) includes Popper for our tooltips and popovers. Hence you no need to install `@popperjs/core` separately.

1. Import the Bootstrap bundle to the *angular.json* `scripts` array.

> angular.json

```
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

---

### Solution 3: Angular Bootstrap

[Angular Bootstrap Dropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples) is another option that makes Bootstrap works in Angular App.

1. Install [Angular Bootstrap (NG Bootstrap)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap).

```
npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

2. Add `NgbModule` into **app.module.ts imports section**.

```js
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [.., NgbModule]
})
```

3. Apply Angular Bootstrap Dropdown directive.

```
<div ngbDropdown class="dropdown">
  <button ngbDropdownToggle class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" aria-expanded="false">
Dropdown button
</button>
  <ul ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a ngbDropdownItem href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a ngbDropdownItem href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a ngbDropdownItem href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Sample Solution 3 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-whxkhx)

Comment: only the third solution worked . when i installed poper core it showed an error and clicked on the dropdown button (both solution 1 and 2 ) it showed     `Uncaught TypeError: i.createPopper is not a function
    at pt._createPopper (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6)`  inbw thanks for the solution no 3 . even though it wasn't what i was looking for ,it still got the job done

Comment: solution 2 too didnt work. Only ngb Module is working

Comment: non of them is working for me

Comment: Solution 3 is OK.

Comment: Solution 1 for me worked. To work that give build before. If you are on run time and make these changes it will not work.

Comment: You must include the Javascript libraries in the order above (Option 1)

Comment: You saved my day on solution 3! thanks!!!

Comment: As @RichardTurner says in the comment above, it is vital that the Javascript libraries are added in the correct order.  Popper first then Bootstrap.  Solution #1 then worked.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: solution 1 worked for me but i used data-bs-toggle instead of data-toggle as shown below

Comment: Worked solution 1 for me, but important thing except order is that you should restart application

Comment: Your solution 3 worked form me for angular 15 and bootstrap 5, after trying lot of things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Solution 1 worked well! just make sure to run `ng serve` after modifying the angular.json or when installing new lib

Answer (score 23):

Add `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` to a link or button to toggle a dropdown

See [the bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#via-data-attributes) to more information.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, but it was the correct answer for my issue.  Specifically, if you are migrating from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 this syntax will need to be updated.

Comment: wow, so many hacks - this is what solved it. only included in my `angular.json` the `bootstrap.bundle` version - and everything worked

Comment: This is the correct answer!  X3

Comment: This approach worked for me... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if still does not work dropdown or other things. you these codes input the index.html file after the

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

People, I was looking for a solution and, in my case, I was using Bootstrap 5x version. I just has uninstall that version (`npm uninstall bootstrap`) and install the last current version of 4x version release (`npm install bootstrap@4 --save`).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Bootstrap Bootstrap  v5.3.2 & Angular: 17.1.0.
to solved this issue I have install

`npm install @popperjs/core`

added below dependencies' in angular.js & restart application.

```
    "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was facing this Issue when i was using Bootstrap 5 & angular12

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown button
      </button>
    
    **And in angular.js**
    "scripts": [
                  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                  "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                ]
```