# Bootstrap collapse not working in Angular 9

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I am having trouble with my navbar not opening up the menu when I change my screen size.

Here are the versions of the dependencies that I am running:

```
"@angular/animations": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

---

I have tried downgrading my jquery as suggested in another post but that didn't do anything.

Here is my HTML:

---

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary my-navbar fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
      <img
    width="200"
    alt="logo"
    src= "assets/imgs/logo.png"
  />
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/userprofile" routerLinkActive="active">Home
              <!--<span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span>-->
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/generalmachining" routerLinkActive="active" >General Machining</a>
            <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/toolreorder" routerLinkActive="active">Tool Re-Ordering</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/setupsheets" routerLinkActive="active">Setup Sheets</a>
          </li>     
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="" >Log Out</a>
          </li>     
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

---

In the HTML I am calling the ID, I have the "#" in the data target and it matches the ID in the dev.

Here are my style and script paths:

---

```
"styles": [
            "src/styles.css",
            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ],
"scripts": [
             "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/custom.js"
           ]
```

---

I feel like I am dealing with a missing package or the wrong version of a package at this point, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 5 dropdown not working on angular 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952309/bootstrap-5-dropdown-not-working-on-angular-12)

Comment: Thank you for your response Yong. It ended up being the "-bs-" was missing in my "data-bs-toggle" and "data-bs-target".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reading the [Bootstrap v5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#toggler). The data attribute names have changed and are now namespaced with a `bs-` prefix. Make the following change and it should work:

```html
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"  data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Arleigh! That did the trick. I missed that I was reading the v4 documentation, and when I followed your link it was right there. I appreciate your time. It looks like I am still too new to upvote, but this was the right answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `bootstrap` in your `angular 9` app like below. This is only for `css` importing.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Now you need to import `bootstrap css` directly in `style.css` file like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

However, if you are required to install `bootstrap` with `jquery` and `popper js` then run the following commands like below:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

After successfully run the above commands import it in `angular.json` file like this:

```
 "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

Comment: Thank Salahuddin for taking the time to respond. It ended up being the "-bs-" was missing in my "data-bs-toggle" and "data-bs-target". I did notice that I don't have the popper script, but I do have "popper.js": "^1.16.1" in the dependencies, so I am not sure if that will have an affect later. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue whenever we upgraded our app to Angular 14. In my case I had to remove [isAnimated] attribute on my menu div tag. It probably had something to do with the packages that got upgraded/removed as part of the migration.