# How to fix Bootstrap Dropdown in vertical nav bar

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a vertical nav bar with a dropdown menu on the third list item in Bootstrap 4, but not matter what I try, my template refuses to display the dropdown options. The template itself is to for an Angular component.

I have already consulted some proposed solutions from this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952309/bootstrap-5-dropdown-is-not-working-on-angular-12) and I looked at the documentation for building dropdowns using [data attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#via-data-attributes) as well as  for building the dropdown component in [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/) and [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/), as I do not see any major changes from one version to the next.

I have recreated the code in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-5-hw6pn8?file=src/index.html).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This can help you, I added  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
and change 
data-bs-toggle in 21 row

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-5-uxcjtc?file=src/index.html

Comment: Hi Nikita, thank you for the input. I added the script into my index.html page and change the data-bs-toggle row and the drop down list does appear, only it is displaying in a single horizontal line.

Comment: Use [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap). The navbar supports 2nd level dropdowns, has a simple api, scss per component, and has `<noscript>` support. [Here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/app.component.html) is how to use it

Comment: Hi Pieter, I cloned the library in a separate folder and tried running `npm start` but I am getting an error related to the `nx` package:
```bash
 >  NX   Cannot find module 'node:fs'
```

I am running node v14.17.3, could this be a version incompatibility problem?

Comment: Could be, but would rather surprise me. I think I'm on Node 16. Did you run `npm i`? You may try `npm install --global nx@latest` too maybe

Comment: [Here's the homepage](https://nx.dev) of NX, the monorepo tool used in the project

Comment: Thanks again. I ran `npm install --global nx@latest` and received the error message:
```bash
>  NX   Could not find Nx modules in this workspace.

Have you run npm/yarn install?
```
So, I tried to install yarn and received the message: `error @angular/animations@15.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.10.0". Got "14.17.3"
error Found incompatible module.` So, my project seems to have a incompatibility problem with my version of node.

I will try to upgrade and see what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry. I created a new Windows 11 VM using **"Hyper-V Quick Create"** - Installed Node 14 (14.21.3) - Installed Git - cloned the repository - cd into the folder - `npm i` - `npm start -- --open` and I don't seem to run into problems. On my DevMachine I'm using Node 16.13.1. You don't even need to install `nx` globally. The version in the project is fine enough

Comment: No worries. My problem is that I am limited to developing an angular project using Angular v.11 as the platform where I hope to deploy the application can only host lower version angular.

Answer (score 0):

You need

1. add "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6" dependensy to package.json

```
     "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "sass": "^1.58.3"
      },
```

2. import bootstrap to index.js

```
import {} from 'bootstrap';
```

3. change data-toggle to data-bs-toggle in html

```
<a
  id="dropdownButton"
  class="nav-item dropdown-toggle"
  role="button"
  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-expanded="false"
>
```

4. add class="dropdown-item" to 4th item(this is just cosmetic)

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownButton">
    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Item 4</a>
 </div>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-5-chpvg8?file=src/index.html