# Angular Bootstrap dropdowns

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I am looking to implement a bootstrap dropdown in Angular.

I have added the bootstrap dependency, and the dropdowns appear but nothing happens when I click them.

```
  <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuSex" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Sex
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuSex">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Female</a>                
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Male</a>                
      </div>
  </div>
```

What have I missed? Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5tgmn2?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftest-form%2Ftest-form.component.ts).

Comment: bootstrap is installed, but you are missed your styles and scrips in `angular.json`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 5 dropdown is not working on Angular 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952309/bootstrap-5-dropdown-is-not-working-on-angular-12)

Comment: you are also missing a package `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Comment: you can play a little bit with an existing playgound [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-bootstrap)

Comment: @MeerArtefakt where do I make all these changes? Could you please post a answer?

Comment: I would start here: [getting-started](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started). but also helpfull can be [@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) and [ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) - direct link to your dropdown: [Dropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)

Answer (score 0):

In your stackblitz you use Bootstrap v5, but your code looks like for v4.

v5 version dropdown example from docs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#overview) uses `data-bs-toggle` attributte:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the Stackblitz first dropdown - but still doesnt work? https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5tgmn2?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftest-form%2Ftest-form.component.html