# navbar not appear in the result?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, navbar

I'm learning on angular 15.0.0 and I have faced an issue

the navbar doesn't appear why  does nothing appear except the Recipe Book

the code

```html
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class ="navbar-brand">Racipe Book!</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shopping list</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role = "button"> Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">saving data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">fetch data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

this is how it looks:
[image: screenshot of app]

I tried to downgrade the Bootstrap but isn't working, and tried to use the **`ng-bootstrap`** package to include Angular-based Bootstrap components. also did not work both gave errors in the terminal

it should be like this:
[image: expected outcome]

Comment: Don't know bootstrap very well but try to remove spaces before and after your class attribute definitions (correct: class="navbar navbar-default", incorrect: class = "navbar navbar-default")

Comment: I tried that still not working, thanks. @MC

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.navbar-expand` class.

[Navbar - How it works | Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#how-it-works)

> Navbars require a wrapping `.navbar` with `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl}` for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

Also, you should need a button toggle to show/hide the collapsible section. Ensure that you have imported either:

1. *popper.min.js* and *bootstrap.min.js* files
2. *bootstrap.bundle.min.js*

in order to make the collapse function work.

Reference: [Bootstrap 5 dropdown is not working on Angular 12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68953199)

Complete code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Racipe Book!</a>
    </div>

    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Recipes</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping list</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="dropdown-toggle"
            role="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarManageContent"
          >
            Manage <span class="caret"></span
          ></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="navbarManageContent">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">saving data</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">fetch data</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jwrdkk?file=index.html)